# Video doesn't play in Processing 3.1.1

Tags: video, processing, osx-elcapitan, .mov, imovie

Brief: When I run this code in Processing it doesn't show anything but an empty window. It works with [sample .mov](http://www.steppublishers.com/sample-video) downloaded from this random website.

Detail:
I am on Mac Os El Capitan (10.11.6) and I have Processing 3.1.1. I used QuickTimePlayer to record a part of my screen(saved as Mariye.mov) and then I used iMovie to speed it up 4 times and the result is saved as Mariye4x.mov. You can see it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kda2mgdrkz1u3u9/Mariye4x.mov?dl=0). I have put it in the Sketch folder in subfolder "data". it's 2:16 minutes/high resolution video. 
When I use this code with some sample .mov files from the internet it works. But when I use my own .mov file it doesn't show anything but an empty sketch window. Any suggestion?

I also used the original Mariye.mov and tried to use "speed(4.0)" function in processing to speed it up and that also doesn't work and the speed doesn't change.

Here is my code:

```java
import processing.video.*;

Movie myMovie;

void setup() {
   fullScreen();
  myMovie = new Movie(this, "Mariye4x.mov");
  myMovie.play();
}

void draw() {

  image(myMovie,0,0);
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}
```

Comment: Can you also upload your movie file somewhere (like dropbox or something) and provide a link to it?

Comment: @KevinWorkman: I have added the link!

Comment: When I try to run your movie just using a regular movie player, I get an error saying it was encoded in a format that's not supported. I assume Processing is choking on something similar. Maybe check your encoding settings?

Comment: @KevinWorkman: Very interesting, because I can play it in QuickTimePlayer easily! How would I check the encoding settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having a quick look at the link, the video file is 1.2GB and it's compressed with the Apple ProRes 422 codec (probably iMovie default).

I've had some performance issues with the Processing video library and 1080p video. I recommend compressing to 720p using H264 encoding.

You can easily do this using Quicktime Player: **File > Export to > 720p**.
In processing, use the 720p compressed version of the video.

I can confirm this works both in Processing 3 and p5.js